# How to check if all $_POST variables are set with foreach loop

Tags: php

I want to check if given $_post variable is set and after that execute a query(which is another theme).But i have a big trouble for 5 hours i cannot really pass it.. There is my function code

```
<?php
function post_category_isset()
{
    global $connect;

    $input = sanitize('category');
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT term_id FROM term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = '$input'");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

        $category_id [] = $row['term_id'];
        $result = '\'' . implode('\',\'', $category_id) . '\'';

        foreach ($row as $result) {

            $query1 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT name FROM terms WHERE term_id = $result");
            $fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1);
            $value = $fetch['name'];
            if (isset($_POST[$value])) {
                echo "if(isset($_POST[$value]) OR";

                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}


?>
```

I have tried everything,and yes the code looks really stupid the way it is right now,but i am depleted ...

So i made that function to check if categories variables are set,which are another function,because i want everything to be automatically .I will paste my other func in pastebin,since it is out of the thread [here](https://pastebin.com/AJt32bts).

So all in short i want to make function which checks if all $_POST variables from previous functions are set and if they are,fire the query.

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly you're trying to do in the second query?

Comment: From first one i am getting the id-s http://prntscr.com/g7viv8 of categories and from second one i am getting category names,which are stored in other table in database http://prntscr.com/g7vjbd

Comment: I've given an answer below, hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use two separate queries here, you can do everything in just one single query.

```
SELECT name 
FROM terms 
WHERE term_id IN (
    SELECT term_id 
    FROM term_taxonomy 
    WHERE taxonomy = '$input'
)
```

So your `post_category_isset()` function would be like this:

```
function post_category_isset(){
    global $connect;

    $input = sanitize('category');
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT name FROM terms WHERE term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = '$input')");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $value = $row['name'];
        if (isset($_POST[$value])) {
            // your code
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you,it definitely works,but the result is the same as mine code,it works only when second id is selected ... if(isset($_POST['bulking'])) only return true,which ID is 26 .. second id from categories other two $_POSt variables return false no matter if they are checked or not ;/ Thanks once again,this code is more readable and shorter than mine <3

Comment: @TsvetomirovYordan There are two things here. 1. As per your code, once this `if` condition `if (isset($_POST[$value])) {` is met, it'll immediately return `true` and thereby terminating the `while` loop there itself, so it won't loop through the rest of the result set once the condition is met. 2. Check whether you're getting all expected contents with `$_POST` or not, do `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: Yap i am getting them as when i do var_dump($_POST),but function return null,do you have any advice how to fix it so it detect if one of all $_POST's is set.And i am accepting this as answer,because it is,if you have any advice on how to fix it,it will be great < 3

Comment: @TsvetomirovYordan Paste the contents of `var_dump($_POST);` on [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/) and give me it's link here. May be this clear up the complete scenario.

Comment: @TsvetomirovYordan `var_dump(...);` doesn't show discrete arrays, so that's not a valid output of `var_dump($_POST);`. Did you edit the contents of `var_dump($_POST);` before pasting on pastebin? If so then do not edit anything, just paste the exact output of `var_dump($_POST);` on pastebin.com and give me it's link here.

Comment: Haven't touched anything mate ,there is picture http://prntscr.com/g7vzyu

Comment: @TsvetomirovYordan I think I understood the issue. If you could look at the database value and `$_POST` value, you would see that `Fat Loss` is stored in the *name* column but `$_POST` has `Fat_Loss` value, see the underscore there. That's why it's not getting matched correctly because `Fat Loss != Fat_Loss`. I would suggest you to send any other column value(other than *name*) with your form submission so that it couldn't get changed later.

Comment: GOSH mate i am watching it from 6 hours already and you saw it for 10 minutes O.o Thank you mate <3 <3

Comment: @TsvetomirovYordan You're welcome! Glad I could help. :-)